# req always undefined in Apollo Server context

Tags: graphql, apollo

i have a problem with the apollo-server context. I wrote the following code:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-azure-functions");
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('../graphql_schema/schema');

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers, 
    context: ({ req }) => {
      console.log(req);
      return {
        req: req
      }
    },
    introspection: false,
    playground: true,
  });

  module.exports = server.createHandler();
```

But the req variable is always undefined.
Does anybody have a idea?

I´m using following versions of apollo

```
"apollo-server": "^2.4.2",
"apollo-server-azure-functions": "^2.4.2",
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

I have a solution for my problem.

```
context: ( {req} ) =>...
```

Don't deconstruct `req`, it should be:

```
context: (req) => ...
```

---

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-azure-functions");
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('../graphql_schema/schema');

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers, 
    context: (req) => {
      return {
        accesstoken: GetAccessToken(req.request)
      }
    },
    introspection: false,
    playground: true,
  });

  const GetAccessToken = function (request){
    const token = (request.headers.authorization || '').replace('BEARER ', '');
    return token;
  }

  module.exports = server.createHandler();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Need to define the req parameter on a top**

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-azure-functions");
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('../graphql_schema/schema');

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    req,
    context: ({ req }) => {
      console.log(req);
      return {
        req: req
      }
    },
    introspection: false,
    playground: true,
  });

  module.exports = server.createHandler();
```